# Is this thread safe with this ConcurrentDictionary and AddOrUpdate method?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, concurrentdictionary

I have a doubt with the concurrent dictionary in C#.

In another question I was asked how to have a concurrent dictionary with a hashset as value, but it isn't a good idea to work with a hashset, it is better to use a concurrent dictionary as value. So the solution that I get was this:

```
var myDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte>>();
myDic.AddOrUpdate(key, 
    _ => new ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte>(new[] {new KeyValuePair<int, byte>(element, 0)}),
    (_, oldValue) => {
        oldValue.TryAdd(element, 0);
        return oldValue;
    });
```

Suppose that I have two threads, where "element" is 1 in the thread A and 2 in the thread B.

My doubt is if this is thread safe. I can be wrong but I think that the concurrent dictionary works in this way:

Thread A: try to insert element 1 for key 1. The key 1 doesn't exist, so it try to insert the key 1 with the concurrent dictionary `ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte>(new[] {new KeyValuePair<int, byte>(1, 0)`.

Thread B: tries to insert the item 2 in the dictionary of key 1. Thread A is still adding the new key/value, Thread B thinks that key 1 doesn't exists, so try to add the value `ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte>(new[] {new KeyValuePair<int, byte>(2, 0)` to the key 1.

Thread A finishes to insert the key/value pair successfully.

Thread B tries to finish, but now it the key 1 exists because thread A inserted the key 1. So the thread B can't insert the key/value.

So what happen? The work of thread B is discard so I will only have one item in the concurrent dictionary for the key 1? Or perhaps thread B enters in the `updateValueFactory` and add the item 2 to the dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AddOrUpdate` is specifically designed to handle the scenario you described; if it could not handle it gracefully, it would be useless.

When thread B tries to add its computed value, it will fail because the key already exists.  It will then *automatically try again*, at which point it will perform an *update* instead of an *add*.  Specifically, it will update the value produced by thread A.  This is a form of *optimistic concurrency*: the algorithm assumes it will succeed, so it optimizes for that outcome, but it has a fallback plan in case it fails.

Note, however, that the optimistically concurrent nature of this method means that your `addValueFactory` and `updateValueFactory` may be *both* be called; it's not strictly one or the other.  In your hypothetical scenario, thread B would first call into `addValueFactory` and, because the add fails, later call into `updateValueFactory`.  In cases of racing updates, `updateValueFactory` may called multiple times before an update finally succeeds.

Comment: Regarding the details (specifically "automatically try again" and the fact that both factories may be called), the source for ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate() is pretty readable and interesting to take a look at: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,e5f450835d8600ed. The factory methods are called outside of the lock in order to minimize the amount of time spent inside of locks, and it's all in a while loop so that multiple attempts can be made until one succeeds in the case of concurrency.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the ways in which the algorithm is optimistic: it eagerly computes the value it _thinks_ it will need, without acquiring any shared resources to do so.  Only when it fails will it try again.  And indeed, the sources are worth exploring.

Answer (score 5):

The way you use the `ConcurrentDictionary` class is brittle. The `AddOrUpdate` is intended for replacing the value of a key with another value, not for modifying existing values, in case the values are mutable objects. And this is exactly what you are doing inside the `updateValueFactory` delegate:

```
(_, oldValue) =>
{
    oldValue.TryAdd(element, 0);
    return oldValue;
}
```

The `oldValue` is a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte>`, and is mutated by invoking its `TryAdd` method. This invocation is not synchronized, it may occur concurrently with an invocation from another thread, and may even be invoked multiple times by each thread. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate):

> However, the `addValueFactory` and `updateValueFactory` delegates are called outside the locks to avoid the problems that can arise from executing unknown code under a lock. Therefore, `AddOrUpdate` is not atomic with regards to all other operations on the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` class.

Now it could be possible that this specific usage is accidentally thread-safe, but personally I would avoid using a `ConcurrentDictionary` like that. It looks like a bug waiting to happen.

Here is how you could rewrite your code, to make it less error-prone, and also clearer regarding its intentions:

```
var innerDic = myDic.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte>());
innerDic.TryAdd(element, 0);
```